# Struts2 submit tag not working in struts2.1.8 with method attribute

Tags: forms, methods, struts2, submit, action

I am upgrading a struts2 app from struts version 2.1.6 to 2.1.8. I have the following submit tag with method attribute, which has stopped working since the upgrade.

```
<s:form action="xyzDetail_save" theme="simple">

<s:submit method="addxyz" value="%{getText('button.add1')}" />
```

There are other struts libraries used like struts-dojo, struts-tiles.
Does anybody have an idea why this wouldnt work? Or can you leave me clue about which interceptor should I debug to get to the bottom of the problem?
Thanks

Comment: It looks like you didn't properly escape your code example. Would you edit your question and follow this guide for formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  Also, when you say that the submit button isn't working, what do you mean? Do you get an exception? Does it do nothing at all?

Comment: It doesn't throw any exception, but goes to the default method for the form action (ignoring the method attribute set in the submit tag). This is old code I am debugging and upgrading to 2.1.8 (from 2.1.6).

Comment: Could you try what happens on 2.2.1 version?

Comment: Vidhya, I am facing the same problem, did you get the solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set DMI to true in your struts.xml (notice that DMI is higly discouraged for security reasons)

```
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.DefaultActionMapper, parseActionName method.
As I told you before and as you will see, you have to set StrutsConstants.STRUTS_ENABLE_DYNAMIC_METHOD_INVOCATION to true.

Comment: I think this is a framework bug. Works fine in 2.1.6, but not in 2.1.8. In 2.1.8, findActionMapping of dofilter in StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter fails to find the mapping and so the default mapping for the action form is getting executed.